# Adding users to a user pool with Amazon Cognito

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to get a grasp on how Amazon Cognito works but the documentation is ever so slightly vague. I've found several API's that appear to do something similar, two from Amazon, and a third on Git Hub that seems to be popular. This last one also appears to be written for browsers and while it does work, it requires polyfills, which add complexity that I'd like to avoid.

The one I'd like to use is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentity.html
But this appears to be the least user friendly of all. There is ample documentation, it just isn't good.

It sounds like you use the function `getId()` to create the user, but there are references to things like "account id" as parameters that just don't make sense.

Which functions do I actually need from this API to add a user to my user pool? should I even use this API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to use it on your web app client, you can look at using `amazon-cognito-identity-js` instead which is documented [here.](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js)

Sample usage of `signUp` below:

```js
 const AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js')
 
 var poolData = {
        UserPoolId : '...', // Your user pool id here
        ClientId : '...' // Your client id here
    };
    var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

    var attributeList = [];

    var dataEmail = {
        Name : 'email',
        Value : 'email@mydomain.com'
    };

    var dataPhoneNumber = {
        Name : 'phone_number',
        Value : '+15555555555'
    };
    var attributeEmail = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(dataEmail);
    var attributePhoneNumber = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(dataPhoneNumber);

    attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
    attributeList.push(attributePhoneNumber);

    userPool.signUp('username', 'password', attributeList, null, function(err, result){
        if (err) {
            alert(err.message || JSON.stringify(err));
            return;
        }
        var cognitoUser = result.user;
        console.log('user name is ' + cognitoUser.getUsername());
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `adminCreateUser` method in the CognitoIdentiyServiceProvider https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html

Note that I'm coming from C++ but this looks to be the same in Javascript.

Comment: I thought about doing that but it seemed weird to use an admin function. Seems like there should be a non admin version of this. In any case I'll give it a shot.

Comment: For anyone wondering in the future, there is a function called signUp() in the same API, that allows you to add users.

Comment: @Carl Good to know; I'm using server side sign-up, so use cases may be different for the two methods.

Comment: Interesting development actually, after looking a bit more closely It doesn't look like there's a parameter anywhere for the pool Id in the signup() function. That kind of throws a wrench in my plans. I thought maybe it was just missing from the documentation, but it won't accept UserPoolId as a property in the parameters object. It says quote "creates a user in the specified user pool". Where exactly that pool id is specified however, is a mystery to me, since it isn't taken as a parameter to the function, nor to the parameters object. I'll see if I can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: In any case, for now I'm just going to move ahead with the adminCreateUser function, since this appears to behave as expected.

Comment: @Carl I haven't tried `signUp` but maybe the `clientID` together with the secret identify the pool.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. This documentation is kind of a chore to dig through. It's harder to locate than it should be, not well explained, and completely lacking in actual examples. That being said, I'm not going to go against the grain if it means a day of research and questions to get to the bottom of it. I'll update tomorrow if someone has an answer to my other question.