# Amazon Cognito User Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a user pool in Amazon Cognito used for authenticating the APIs. And I have a user table in my database RDS where user will be inserted via application and website. I am looking for a way to auto insert user in Cognito user pool when user gets inserted in user table.
I am using java as the programming language.

Can anyone please suggest me any possible solution for it?

Can I use lambda for this? And if I can, is there any example for it, where users are inserted using lambda using java sdk?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding users to a user pool with Amazon Cognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55642165/adding-users-to-a-user-pool-with-amazon-cognito)

Comment: The above link is JS - not Java

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **AWS SDK for Java v2** to perform this task. To add a user to a user Pool, you can use this Java code. Specifically, you use the [software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoIdentityProviderClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/cognitoidentityprovider/CognitoIdentityProviderClient.html) and use the [signUp](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/cognito/src/main/java/com/example/cognito/SignUpUser.java) method.

If you are not familiar with the AWS SDK for Java V2, refer to the [DEV Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html).

Code to add a user to a user pool is:

```
package com.example.cognito;

//snippet-start:[cognito.java2.new_admin_user.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoIdentityProviderClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.AdminCreateUserRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.AdminCreateUserResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.AttributeType;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.CognitoIdentityProviderException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
//snippet-end:[cognito.java2.new_admin_user.import]

/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */
public class CreateUser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String usage = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    <userPoolId> <userName> <email> <password>\n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    userPoolId - The Id value for the user pool where the user is created.\n\n" +
                "    userName - The user name for the new user.\n\n" +
                "    email - The email to use for verifying the user.\n\n" +
                "    password - The password for this user.\n\n" ;

        if (args.length != 4) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String userPoolId = args[0];
        String userName = args[1];
        String email = args[2];
        String password = args[3];

        CognitoIdentityProviderClient cognitoClient = CognitoIdentityProviderClient.builder()
                .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
                .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
                .build();

        createNewUser(cognitoClient, userPoolId, userName, email, password);
        cognitoClient.close();
    }

    //snippet-start:[cognito.java2.add_login_provider.main]
    public static void createNewUser(CognitoIdentityProviderClient cognitoClient,
                                   String userPoolId,
                                   String name,
                                   String email,
                                   String password){

        try{
            AttributeType userAttrs = AttributeType.builder()
                    .name("email")
                    .value(email)
                    .build();

            AttributeType userAttrs1 = AttributeType.builder()
                    .name("autoVerifyEmail")
                    .value("true")
                    .build();

            List<AttributeType> userAttrsList = new ArrayList();
            userAttrsList.add(userAttrs);
            userAttrsList.add(userAttrs1);

            AdminCreateUserRequest userRequest = AdminCreateUserRequest.builder()
                    .userPoolId(userPoolId)
                    .username(name)
                    .temporaryPassword(password)
                    .userAttributes(userAttrs)
                    .messageAction("SUPPRESS")
                    .build() ;

            AdminCreateUserResponse response = cognitoClient.adminCreateUser(userRequest);
            System.out.println("User " + response.user().username() + "is created. Status: " + response.user().userStatus());

        } catch (CognitoIdentityProviderException e){
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    //snippet-end:[cognito.java2.add_login_provider.main]
}
```

Code to sign up a user is:

```
//snippet-sourcedescription:[SignUp.java demonstrates how to register a user in the specified Amazon Cognito user pool.]
//snippet-keyword:[AWS SDK for Java v2]
//snippet-keyword:[Code Sample]
//snippet-keyword:[Amazon Cognito]
//snippet-sourcetype:[full-example]
//snippet-sourcedate:[05/18/2022]
/*
   Copyright Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
   SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
*/

package com.example.cognito;

//snippet-start:[cognito.java2.signup.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoIdentityProviderClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.CognitoIdentityProviderException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.SignUpRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.AttributeType;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
//snippet-end:[cognito.java2.signup.import]

/**
 * To run this Java code example, you need to create a client app in a user pool with a secret key. For details, see:
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-client-apps.html
 *
 * In addition, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 *  For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 *
 */

public class SignUpUser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String usage = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    <clientId> <secretkey> <userName> <password> <email>\n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    clientId - The app client id value that you can obtain from the AWS Management Console.\n\n" +
                "    secretkey - The app client secret value that you can obtain from the AWS Management Console.\n\n" +
                "    userName - The user name of the user you wish to register.\n\n" +
                "    password - The password for the user.\n\n" +
                "    email - The email address for the user.\n\n";

        if (args.length != 5) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String clientId = args[0];
        String secretKey = args[1];
        String userName = args[2];
        String password = args[3];
        String email = args[4];

        CognitoIdentityProviderClient identityProviderClient = CognitoIdentityProviderClient.builder()
                .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
                .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
                .build();

        signUp(identityProviderClient, clientId, secretKey, userName, password, email);
        identityProviderClient.close();
    }

    //snippet-start:[cognito.java2.signup.main]
    public static void signUp(CognitoIdentityProviderClient identityProviderClient,
                                  String clientId,
                                  String secretKey,
                                  String userName,
                                  String password,
                                  String email) {

        AttributeType attributeType = AttributeType.builder()
                .name("email")
                .value(email)
                .build();

        List<AttributeType> attrs = new ArrayList<>();
        attrs.add(attributeType);

       try {
           String secretVal = calculateSecretHash(clientId, secretKey, userName);
           SignUpRequest signUpRequest = SignUpRequest.builder()
                   .userAttributes(attrs)
                   .username(userName)
                   .clientId(clientId)
                   .password(password)
                   .secretHash(secretVal)
                   .build();

           identityProviderClient.signUp(signUpRequest);
           System.out.println("User has been signed up");

       } catch(CognitoIdentityProviderException e) {
           System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
           System.exit(1);
       } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

    public static String calculateSecretHash(String userPoolClientId, String userPoolClientSecret, String userName) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
        final String HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA256";

        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(
                userPoolClientSecret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);

        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
        mac.init(signingKey);
        mac.update(userName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(userPoolClientId.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(rawHmac);
    }
    //snippet-end:[cognito.java2.signup.main]
}
```

This code example assumes that the user pool requires a Client secret when adding a user. More info here:

[Configuring a user pool app client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-client-apps.html)

After you get the user details from the database, use this Cognito code to add the user to a user pool. Notice you need these input values:

- **clientId** - The app client id value that you can obtain from the AWS Management Console.\n\n" +
- **secretkey** - The app client secret value that you can obtain from the AWS Management Console.\n\n" +
- **userName** - The user name of the user you wish to register.\n\n" +
- **password** - The password for the user.\n\n" +
- **email** - The email address for the user.\n\n";

This Java code can be wrapped in an AWS Lambda function that uses the Java Lambda runtime API.